# Cannot import bootstrap in my Rails application.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am getting the error

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
```

and

> Extracted source (around line #1):
>
> ```
> @import 'bootstrap';
> ```

while importing bootstrap.

I tried renaming and restarting the server for so many different ways but still did not work.

Comment: do you have the bootstrap gem installed?

Comment: Edited, don't use screenshots of error messages or code in your IDE. Include the relevant code in your question and the text of the error message. Screenshots are only useful for demonstrating browser related issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` installed with the proper version, did you add `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` before `@import "bootstrap";`? I believe the sprockets part needs to be added first in your scss file. Hope that helps.